# vscode highlight directory errors

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there an extension or setting in vscode that will show an error when an `import` or `require` path is not entered correctly or doesn't resolve.

For example, I would like vscode to underline or highlight this line because `lodash/gets` is not correct.

```
const _get = require('lodash/gets'); <--- error
```

Or, can vscode underline or highlight any custom module pointing to the wrong path?

```
const myModule = require('../../some/wrong/path/to/my/module'); <--- error
```